# Web image resizing with Lanczo's Algorithm - which language do I use?

Tags: php, algorithm, image, resize

I need to make an online image resizing program that uses the Lanczo's Algorithm, which I hear is the best algorithm to reduce image size. How would I go about doing this? I have knowledge of PHP but I'm willing to learn other languages if I need to.

I understand that PHP does have it's own image resize function, but it's not very good compared to Lanczo's so would it be possible to change the PHP resize algorithm to Lanczo's?

If not, are there are other programming languages that make it easier to write an image resize tool in?

Thanks

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818603/issues-porting-php-gd-wrapper-to-imagick) and the possible future answers might help you make a decision. Even with the Lanczo filter, ImageMagick doesn't seem to be *that* good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick can utilize Lanczo's algorithm:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-resizeimage.php
(check out the *filter* argument)